# Setting ModalPopupExtender TargetControlID to LIstView Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, simplemodal

I am wondering how I am able to set the `TargetControlID` of my `ModalPopupExtender` to the Button on my `ListView`.

The button that I am trying to set the `TargetControlID` to is in the Alternating and Item template on the ListView. So I believe I would need to set the `TargetControlID` to either two buttons, or have two different `ModalPopupExtenders`.

Here is my `ModalPopupExtender`:

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panl1" TargetControlID="Button1"
    CancelControlID="Button2" BackgroundCssClass="Background"  OnLoad="mp1_Load">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

And here is the alternating template for my listview:

```
<AlternatingItemTemplate>
 <!--Input fields that do not apply to the question-->
 ..
 ..
 ..
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show Popup" />
</AlternatingItemTemplate>
```

This will be the exact same setup for the ItemTemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use java-script to do the job instead:

```
<a id="showModalPopupClientButton" href="#">Open pop-up</a>
<a id="hideModalPopupViaClientButton" href="#">Close pop-up</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Add click handlers for buttons to show and hide modal popup on pageLoad
    function pageLoad() {
        $addHandler($get("showModalPopupClientButton"), 'click', showModalPopupViaClient);
        $addHandler($get("hideModalPopupViaClientButton"), 'click', hideModalPopupViaClient);        
    }

    function showModalPopupViaClient(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var modalPopupBehavior = $find('programmaticModalPopupBehavior');
        modalPopupBehavior.show();
    }

    function hideModalPopupViaClient(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();        
        var modalPopupBehavior = $find('programmaticModalPopupBehavior');
        modalPopupBehavior.hide();
    }
</script>
```

**UPDATE (using server side)**
You need to set a fake server button(display: none) as a target control id to your popup extender first:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Style="display: none;" />
 <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" 
    PopupControlID="Panl1"      TargetControlID="Button1"
    CancelControlID="Button2" BackgroundCssClass="Background"  
    OnLoad="mp1_Load">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

on your code behind whenever you want to display or close the popup, you just need to call the following functions:

```
  mp1.Show();    //to display popup

  mp1.Hide()     //to close popup
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was on lunch. I will give this a try and let you know if it works.

Comment: I gave this a try, but I get the error message `Cannot read property 'show' of null.`. I don't believe it is finding the control on the page.

Comment: try the server side solution, I hope it helps

Comment: Flailed around a bit, but I got it to work with your help. Thanks!!